# text not populating after hyphen in textbox from vb listview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am working on an ASPX VB.NET web app that lets you search from a list of job titles and when you select a job title and click the add button it adds the job title to the textbox called tbJobTitle.

The problem is that when there is a job title with a hyphen in it only the 1st part of the title is passed to tbJobTitle so for example if you have the job title called `1234--admin assistant - IT admin` as the job title only the `admin assistant` gets sent to the `tbJobTitle` textbox. I need the whole thing to pass to the `tbJobTitle` textbox.

Here is my .vb code:

```
Private Sub btnAddTitle_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddTitle.Click 
    For Each item As ListItem In lbJobTitle.Items
        If item.Selected Then
            If Not lbTitles.Items.Contains(item) Then
                lbTitles.Items.Add(item)
                Dim str As String = lbTitles.SelectedItem.Text
                Dim strArr As String() = Nothing
                Dim splitchar As Char() = {"--"}
                strArr = str.Split(splitchar)
                tbJobTitle.Text = strArr(2)
            End If
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You know that `strArr(2)` returns the third string in the array not the second?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because microsoft decided to set [option strict](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) to `off` as default. So every new developer runs in such ugly bugs. Normally this gives a compiler error. Why?

Because this is not valid:

```
Dim splitchar As Char() = {"--"}
```

You are initializing a `Char()` with a single `String`. Valid would be this(note the `"-"c`):

```
Dim splitchar As Char() = {"-"c} ' this will split by a single hyphen
```

Now, what happens if Option Strict is set to Off? it will compile and introduce a much worse bug. It will silently take the first char of the string and use that. So you actually get this array:

```
Dim splitchar As Char() = {"-"c} ' this will split by a single hyphen
```

which is not what you wanted. This is what you wanted(note the `String()`):

```
Dim splitStrings As String() = {"--"} ' this will split by  double hyphen
strArr = str.Split(splitStrings, StringSplitOptions.None))
```

You need [the overload of `String.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes a `String()` and  `StringSplitOptions`.

I strongly recommend to set `Option Strict` to `On` and learn to write type safe and clean code.

---

Here is a class that demonstrates the whole mess:

```
Option Strict Off

Public Class OptionStrictDemo
    Shared sub ShowMess()
        Dim aChar As Char = "f"c
        Dim otherChar As Char = "foo"
        Dim isMess = aChar = otherChar
        Console.Write("Is it a mess? " & if(isMess, "yes", "no")) ' Is it a mess? yes
    End sub
End Class
```

If you'd set `Option Strict On`(better make it default) you would get a compiler error.